# Simple SQL Connection Class to use for CRUD ops and transactions

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have been trying to write an sql connection class for a small project,which will use simple sql commands for insert/update/select/delete ops and sometimes with transactions,is there any guidelines i could use? The class could be instantiated at any point with or without transactions...

Tried:

```
public class DbConnection

{
    public static string srConnectionString = "blablab";

public DbConnection()
{

}

public static DataSet db_Select_Query(string strQuery)
{
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(srConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter _SqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strQuery, connection);
            DA.Fill(dataSet);
        }
        return dataSet;
    }

    catch (Exception)
    {
         //some error handling.
    }
}

public static void db_Update_Delete_Query(string strQuery)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(srConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strQuery, connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
         //some error handling.
    }
}
```

For example how can i add a parameter that opens or closes transaction as long as this class is used?For example i could be able to call db.commit or db.rollback from outside the class.

PS:tried some micro orms(petapoco for ex.) ,is there a way to run them with pure sql and get return type as datasets or datatables only?

Regards.

Edit:

```
  public class dbconnection : IDisposable
{
    public static string strConnectionString = @"Data Source=PC137\PC137_SQL2008;Initial Catalog=BARZO;Integrated Security=True";

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    #endregion

    private SqlTransaction transaction;
    private SqlConnection connection;
    private SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();


    public void db_OpenConnection(bool WithTransaction)
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
        connection.Open();

        if (WithTransaction)
        {
            transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
        }
    }


    public void db_CloseConnection()
    {
        connection.Close();
        connection.Dispose();
        transaction.Dispose();
        command.Dispose();
    }


    public void db_Commit()
    {
        transaction.Commit();
    }


    public void db_RollBack()
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
    }


    public DataSet db_Select_Query(string strQuery)
    {
        var dataSet = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter SqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strQuery, connection);
            SqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
            return dataSet;
        }

        catch (SqlException sqlError)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(sqlError,MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
        }
    }

    public bool db_Update_Delete_Query(string strQuery)
    {
        try
        {
            command = new SqlCommand(strQuery, connection);
            command.Transaction = transaction;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlError)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(sqlError,MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just one caveat: SqlCommand is disposable, so you'll need to add a using statement.

Answer (score 1):

I would make the `db_Update_Delete_Query()` method return your own `DbCommandToken`, which wraps an `SqlTransaction` object, and can be used to cancel the transaction or report the completion of the command.

This would look like this.

```
public class DbConnection
{
    public static DbCommandToken db_Update_Delete_Query(string strQuery)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strQuery, connection);
                return new DbCommandToken(transaction, command);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //some error handling.
        }
    }
}
```

Note that both your command and your transaction are now owned by your `DbCommandToken` object, which should implement `IDisposable`.

If your command is a long-running command, which you may want to run asynchronously, and maybe cancel with a later request, you can add success and failure callbacks to your `DbCommandToken`: something along these lines.

```
public class DbCommandToken : IDisposable
{
    private readonly SqlTransaction _transaction;
    private readonly SqlCommand _command;

    public DbCommandToken(SqlTransaction transaction, SqlCommand command)
    {
        _transaction = transaction;
        _command = command;
    }

    public Action Success { get; set; }

    public Action Failure { get; set; }

    public Task<int> Execute()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _command.ExecuteNonQuery())
            .ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    var rowsAffected = t.Result;
                    if (rowsAffected >= 0)
                    {
                        _transaction.Commit();
                        Success();
                    }

                    ...Handle other scenarios here...

                    return t.Result;
                });
    }

    public void Cancel()
    {
        _transaction.Rollback();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _command.Dispose();
        _transaction.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: But if i dont open a transaction,how can it return a value? The point it on what spot should i open the transaction?

Comment: Cheers.Then the usage would be : 
                String insert2 = @"INSERT INTO BARZO.dbo.Table_1
                                      ( A, B )
                                    VALUES
                                      ( N'CCC', -- A - nchar(10)
                                        N'DDD'  -- B - nchar(10)
                                        )";






                _dbconnection.db_Update_Delete_Query(insert2).Execute(); right? How can i just call the class and run the execute commands a couple of times,then do the commit?

Comment: OK, my bad.  I misunderstood what you were asking for.  The first question that occurs to me is, do you need the wrapper class at all?  Can you just do the whole thing with a `SqlConnection` that creates transactions using `BeginTransaction`, and `SqlCommand` objects that you run on the fly? Is the wrapper class just a way of making that process less verbose?

Comment: Nice.  The only change I'd suggest is to make `command` a local variable rather than a member variable, and wrap it in a using statement.  Otherwise, the second time you call `db_Update_Delete_Query`, you'll overwrite your first instance, and that instance won't get disposed.

Comment: Oh, and I'd dispose of the transaction before closing the connection in your `Dispose()` method.  Then it looks like you're good to go.